# emacs, keybinding in iterm2

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'd like to use the following key mapping

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-region) ;doesn't work in shell
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-DEL") 'indent-region) ;doesn't work in shell
```

I have the following setup

1. iterm2 sends escape sequences `^[[1;39` and `^[[1;41` respectively
2. emacs has the following setup

   ```el
   (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;39" (kbd "C-M-;"))
   (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;41" (kbd "C-M-DEL"))
   ```

Still `C-M-;` is only recognized as `M-3`, and `C-M-DEL` is recognized as `1`

**EDIT**

Actually it works with

```
 (defadvice terminal-init-xterm (after map-S-up-escape-sequence
                                       activate)

   (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;39" (kbd "C-M-;"))
   (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;41" (kbd "C-M-DEL"))
   )


 (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;39" (kbd "C-M-;"))
 (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;41" (kbd "C-M-DEL"))
```